# Que signifie cette phrase: "de l'ordre du mois"

Tags: terminologie, unités, ambiguïté

Je voudrais savoir à combien de temps correspond la durée exprimée par cette phrase :

> la durée de cette phase est **de l'ordre du mois**.

Un mois ou plusieurs mois ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means "around one month".

Here *de l'ordre* means *de l'ordre de grandeur*, i.e. the "order of magnitude".